# How to convert this code to coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have the following code:

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
  $(".checkbox").each( function() {
    $(this).attr("checked",status);
  })
}
```

I don't know how to change the each clause and anonymous function inside it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
toggleChecked = (status) ->
  $(".checkbox").each ->
    $(this).attr "checked", status
```

Note that you can use [Js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) to convert JavaScript into CoffeeScript.